# use a sql select statement to get parameters for 2nd select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a sql statement that

I have 2 tables Store & StoreTransactions. 
My first select command looks like

```
SELECT [StoreID],[ParentStoreID] 
FROM Store
```

Very simple stuff. How do I take the returned StoreID's and use them for my 2nd select statement?

```
SELECT [StoreTransactionID],[TransactionDate],[StoreID]
FROM StoreTransactions
WHERE StoreID = returned values from the above query
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT [StoreTransactionID],[TransactionDate],[StoreID]
FROM StoreTransactions
WHERE StoreID in (select StoreId from Store)
```

This is known as a nested select, or inner select.

Comment: Hi Joel,
I get an error Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. 
I will look further into nested selects.

Thank you

Comment: RE: Your error You must have changed this part to have more than one column? *select StoreId from Store* or are using = instead of in?

Comment: @diver, When using in, your nested select must return an array like set (i.e. one column). Notice the sql I wrote only has one field in the nested select.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of other ways of doing it...

```
SELECT [StoreTransactionID],[TransactionDate],[StoreID]
FROM StoreTransactions st
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT * 
FROM Store s
WHERE s.[StoreID] = st.[StoreID]
)
```

And

```
SELECT [StoreTransactionID],[TransactionDate],st.[StoreID]
FROM StoreTransactions st
INNER JOIN Store s ON s.[StoreID] = st.[StoreID]
```

Comment: Both good suggestions. Personally I prefer an inner join to a nested select.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way of writing it is to use an INNER JOIN

```
SELECT [StoreTransactionID],[TransactionDate],[StoreTransactions.StoreID]
FROM StoreTransactions INNER JOIN Store ON StoreTransactions.StoreID=Store.StoreID
```

This may be more efficient in some RDBMSs.

If your Store query also includes a WHERE clause, you can just add that to the query above.